# c++ output char to file give wrong value

Tags: c++, byte, ofstream

I'm trying to write some value to a file byte by byte while when it comes to the value of 10, it write 0D0A instead of only 0A ot the file, any idea?

```
unsigned char m = 10;
ofstream fout("1.file");
fout << m;
fout.close();
```

[output of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgYde.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're on a Windows system, where newlines (`'\n'`, [ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) value `10`) are automatically translated to the Windows newline `"\r\n"` ([ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) values `13` and `10`).

This translation happens for all files opened in text mode on Windows. And in the opposite direction when reading. Opening in binary mode will not do this translation.

Comment: Yes, I'm on windows system, but i didn't open it by any text editor but directly read the file by another program, and still cause this translation, is there any solutions to prevent it? Or how can I only write 0A to the file?

Comment: You could open the file in binary mode. See the `mode` parameter in the constructor of `ofstream`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes expands on what Some programmer due explained.

Comment: Appreciate!! I'll check it out!